# How do I install LaTeX package on-the-fly on Mac?

Tags: packages, miktex, texmaker, mactex

I am trying to use the resume document class `res.cls` but Texmaker is throwing an error that the file is not found. I am new to Mac, when I was using Windows MiKTeX helped me install packages on-the-fly. Is there a way to install LaTeX packages on-the-fly on Mac OsX 10.9?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.sx. This is more or less the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3997 I'd say. Note that TeX Live (which is used by MacTex) is a little bit more restrictive than MikTeX with regards to licensing of packages, so there may be packages that exists in MikTeX but not in MacTeX. MacTeX by default does a complete installation I think, so missing packages has to be installed manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but your MacTeX should already have everything TeX Live have to offer from CTAN (the archive). Remember that some stuff on CTAN are not allowed in TeX Live due to licensing issues. (TeX Live have some strict licence rules and DVDs with TeX Live are sold in Germany)

According to CTAN, http://ctan.org/pkg/res, the `res` class has a no-sell license and is thus not allowed in MacTeX. You will have to install it by hand if you want to use it.

(updated 2015 with cfrs commet)

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that MacTeX should already include everything *TeX Live* has to offer. As you go on to show, CTAN includes packages which are not permitted in TeX Live or which are excluded for some other reason (author preference, instability, lack of portability, dependence on non-free stuff although free themselves, obsolete etc. etc.).